# What is the definition of a definable set of statements, and what is a constructive way to think of this regarding Tarski's Undefinability Theorem?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Logic and model theory are not my area so my thinking is probably off, but I am curious about this so please go ahead and set me straight.

A definable set is one for which there is a formula that is true precisely on input from that set. For example over $\mathbb{N}$ the formula "$\phi(p):\forall x,y\ \big[(\neg p=1)\wedge(p=xy\rightarrow (p=x)\vee(p=y))\big]$" defines the prime numbers, and over $\mathbb{R^2}$ the formula "$\phi(x,y):y=x^2$" defines the standard parabola. More generally (ignoring n-ary relations now) over a set $S$ a formula $\phi(x)$ defines the set $\{x\in S\mid\phi(x)\equiv T\}$.

Now take $S$ to be the set of all statements in a language. It seems that Tarski's theorem essentially says that there is no formula defining the set $\{x\in S\mid x\equiv T\}$. Since $x$ is a variable and not a formula, we cannot just replace $\phi(x)$ in the definition with $x$ itself and be done with it. I wonder then what *is* considered a formula in this context.

As far as I know, Tarski's proof involves coding the statements as natural numbers similar to the Gödel numbering, and then showing that the numbers which correspond to true statements cannot be defined by a formula in the same language (regardless of the coding used). But would there be a way to think about this using formulas over a set of statements? Naively, perhaps a formula would look like (for example) "$\phi(x):P\vee Q\rightarrow x$" where $P$ and $Q$ are fixed statements and $x$ represents a variable statement in $S$. In this case though there is nothing stopping us from calling $x$ by itself a formula which is a problem.

When using numbers, the symbols from arithmetic (particularly the "=" symbol) lend another level of truth which avoids nonsense like $\phi(x):x$. In the attempt in the previous paragraph those symbols are absent, or rather they become nested inside the constants/elements. So could we introduce another level of truth by instead taking formulas to be things like "$\phi(x):((P\vee Q\rightarrow x)\equiv(P\vee x))$" and then bumping up our meta-equivalence to 4 bars, writing the defined set as $\{x\in S\mid\phi(x)\underline{\equiv}T\}$?

Is anything like that done? Does this make any sense? If so can it be used to see why the set $T\subset S$ is undefinable?

Comment: Your formula defining the primes should include $\lnot (p = 1)$.

Comment: This theorem, like Godel's one, applies to *formal theories*; thus, the "criteria" of what "count as" a formula must be clearly specified. For example, if $T$ is a symbol denoting "the truth", to assume that we can meaningfully use it in the language is a sort of "begging" the question ...

Comment: And also the "definability" concept to be used is a precise one : *definability in a sructure*. A set $S$ is definable in (the structure) $\mathfrak N$ **iff** there is a formula $\varphi$ (of the "appropriate" language) such that $a \in S$ **iff** $\mathfrak N \vDash \varphi(a)$ (see Primo's answer).

Comment: @Alex_Kruckman: I made that correction to the formula defining the primes.

Comment: @Mauro_ALLEGRANZA: I see what you mean about including $T$ in the language but I believe Tarski went down a route sort of like at one point in defining a hierarchy of truthes $T_0, T_1, T_2,\dots$ based on levels of nesting similar to this. I think my issue is in understanding the difference between language and structure.

Comment: @j0equ1nn - a *first-order* language is a very very simplified "model" of natural language. It shares with our "innate" feeling that the language refers to a reality "out there" (the world) through the *semantics*. The formal semantical specification for a f-o language are based on the concept of *structure* (the "world out there) and of *interpretation*, i.e. a function (a "process") that assign  to each "meaningful" expression of the language (the *terms*, i.e. "names", and the well-formed formulae) a reference and a truth-value.

Comment: Thus, having fixed a structure like $\mathbb N$ and an intepretation for the f-o language of arithmetic, we have defined an interpretation for the *terms* : $0, 1, S(1), \ldots$ i.e. we have defined which "objects" of the structure the "names" of the language refers to, and we have defined which (closed) formulae (i.e. sentences) are true in $\mathbb N$, according to the said interpretation, like $\lnot \exists n (0 = S(n))$. The "coding mechanism" devised by Godel is a "formal" way to implement in the f-o language for arithmetic a basic feature of natural language : ...

Comment: ... the *self-reference* mechanism in place in every schoolbook grammer. All this is quite "simple" from a conceptual point of view: the basic issue is that we are working in the mathematical field (math log **is** a branch of math) and thus all the above concepts : f-o language, structure, intepretation, "self-reference" mechanism, must be formally (i.e. precisely) specified. This is the only way to prove rigorous (i.e.mathematical) facts about these concepts, like Godel's and Traski's theorems.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Indeed I am phrasing the problem in a way that simplifies it to the point of triviality (sort of missing the depth of what Tarski did). I find this often an effective way of understanding techniques and notation before moving on the the actual method. What to me seems the genius of Godel & Tarski's proofs is the part where they are able to feed the set of statements back in to the language of arithmetic by enumerating them. What I'm wondering is if there's a way of seeing the concept (simplified or otherwise) without turning statements into numbers.

Comment: @j0equ1nn - you can see e.g. Raymond Smullyan, [Diagonalization and Self-Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=uH53QgAACAAJ) (1994), that treats self-refernce in a "general" setting.

Comment: The Godel's trick of encoding associates (in a computable way) a (natural) number to a sentence in the language. Using $G(\sigma)$ to denote the Godel's number associated to the sentence $\sigma$, we can simply reduce the problem of "definability" of a set of sentences to that of the definability of a set of number : the set $\Sigma$ of sentences is *definable* iff the corresponding set of Godel's number is, where the corresponding set $\Sigma_G$ is  such that : $\sigma \in \Sigma$ **iff** $G(\sigma) \in \Sigma_G$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: That looks like an excellent reference. Perhaps to be fully satisfied with an answer to my question it requires that I study something like that. Since this commented conversation is getting lengthy would you care to summarize what you told me in an answer & include that reference? You've been helpful.

Comment: I'd just add that you don't need literally numbers to pull the trick off, any coding scheme will do. For instance, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ you will use sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mixes syntax and semantic and it is not completely understandable to me. Below I restate Tarki's paradox keeping the two levels well-separated, maybe this helps.

Fix a model $M$ and a positive integer $n$. By $L(M)$ we denote the set of all formulas with parameters in $M$. Let $x$ be a tuple of variables of length $|x|=n$. An *$n$-truth predicate* is a formula $\vartheta(x,y)\in L(M)$ such that for every formula $\varphi(x)\in L(M)$ there is an $a\in M^{|y|}$ such that $M\models\forall x\ \big[\vartheta(x,a)\leftrightarrow\varphi(x)\big]$.

Without any further requirement on $M$, existence of $n$-truth predicates is unproblematic. For instance, take for $M$ an infinite dimensional vector space, then $x=y$ is a $1$-truth predicate (by quantifier elimination). In general, the existence of an $n$-truth predicate does not imply the existence of a $(n+1)$-truth predicate.

Now suppose that in $M$ there is a definable encoding of pairs. That is, a definable bijection $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:M^2\to M$. Then from any  $1$-truth predicate we can easily construct an $n$-truth predicate for arbitrary $n$.

This is too good to be consistent! In fact, diagonalization strikes:

Suppose $\vartheta(x,y)\in L(M)$ is a $1$-truth predicate. Clealy we can assume $|y|=1$. For better legibility, we also assume that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a term in the language. Let $\varphi(x)=\neg\vartheta(\langle x,y\rangle)$ and obtain a contradiction as usual.

Comment: I can see why you might say I am confusing syntax with semantics because I admit I don't entirely understand the difference. I have a feeling that semantics is something like a higher level of syntax which allows us to discuss more complexly the statements encoded in the syntax, but maybe that is not a constructive way of thinking? When you say you are keeping the two levels well separated in your explanation, can you identify which parts are which and why they are different?

Comment: Your answer is a good refresher on the standard approach to such problems but I think my confusion results from the notation of the standard approach. There seems some serious difference between defining subsets of a set of numbers with arithmetic properties (using formulas), and defining subsets of a set of statements (also using formulas?). In your view is there no difference there?